# returning multiple values in Java

Tags: java, return-value

Preamble: I am aware of using a list or other collections to return a result but then I have to go through the list plucking the results out: see 2nd example

Preamble-2: I'm looking for an answer beyond "this is not supported in Java ..."

---

I'm looking for a convenient way to return multiple objects from a Java method call.

Kind of like in PHP:

```
list ($obj1, $obj2, ...) foobar();
```

I'm really getting tired of passing holder objects in the arguments for example:

```
class Holder {
   int value;
}

Holder h1=new Holder();
Holder h2=new Holder();
```

and then:

```
o.foobar(h1,h2);
```

... would be very interested if someone has figured an elegant way to get round this.

---

Using a list

```
List<String> = foobar();
```

There are two drawbacks to this:

I have to first pack the List on the callee side of the house:

```
// this is on the callee side of the house
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>
result.add("foo");
result.add("bar");
```

Then on the caller side I have to pluck the results out:

```
// This is on the caller side
List<String> result = foobar();
String result1 = result.get(0);
String result2 = result.get(1); // this is not as elegant as the PHP equivalent
```

Further, say I wanted to return objects of different types say String, Integer I would have to return a list of Objects and then cast each object ... not pretty

Thanks.

Comment: I'd simply return a list

Comment: What's the problem with returning List?

Comment: Edited.  An "old hand" at Java wouldn't ask this question, and the original came across as a bit snarky.

Comment: @Adam-Liss -- perhaps and Older hand than you would :-( ... childish response!!!

Comment: If it isn't supported, it isn't supported. Simple as that. You can use arrays or other collections with the well known drawbacks - especially with the inconvenient boilerplate to put a List up. Use scala instead, and you get Tuples. You can use Tuples from Java, of course, but not in that elegant way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a generic tuple class is the closest I can imagine. To give an idea, such general purpose class for three return values could look something like this:

```
public class T3<A, B, C> {
    A _1;
    B _2;
    C _3;
    T3(A _1, B _2, C _3) {
        this._1 = _1;
        this._2 = _2;
        this._3 = _3;
    }
}
```

This allows a one statement constructor on the callee side, for example:

```
public T3<String, Integer, Character> getValues() {
    return new T3<String, Integer, Character>("string", 0, 'c');
}
```

but no holder instance construction by the callee is to be done.

Each number of return values needs a tuple-class of its own. There might be something like that provided in the [Functional Java library](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava/). For reference, here's an [N-Tuple implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642623).

For the two-valued case java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry would do:

```
return new SimpleEntry<String, Integer>("string", 0);
```

Anyhow, I see two important points to consider for multiple return values:

1. Typed return values
2. Pointing out the meaning of each return value

As boring as it is, I'd recommend creating a separate class to hold all the response values and declare that as the method return type. That way the meaning of each value can be highlighted.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a method like with a signature like this :

```
List<Holder> foobar();
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you return a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), or [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: I can but this is rather cumbersome solution -- refer to example 2 in my question

Answer (score 2):

Returning an extended Holder seems better than returning a List:

```
class Holder {
    int value1;
    String value2;
    Holder(int value1, String value2) {}
}

Holder foobar() {
    return new Holder(1, "bar");
}
```

Comment: Ya, possibly but verbose verbose verbose :-(, thanks for the response though

Comment: @user1172468 Verbosity is Java's inherent property. Sometimes I long for C++ typedef and operator overload magic, but they make a mess, so I am glad for Java being verbose.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to return multiple values of the same type, then a List or Set is appropriate. It is perfectly valid to return, for example, a variable-length username list as a List. If you know you are always going to return a fixed number of values, I would use an array. For example, in a method that returns a some kind of user ID as three distinct integers, I would use:

```
public int[] getUserId(){
    int[] returnArray = new int[3];
    returnArray[0] = getFirstPart();
    returnArray[1] = getSecondPart();
    returnArray[2] = getThirdPart();

    return returnArray;
}
```

In the caller code, obtaining the values is as simple as `array[0]`, `array[1]` and `array[2]`. This is much easier than a Collection, and you will not break anything, because user IDs are defined as being three integers.

If you really need to return multiple distinct values, then the holder class is the best option, no other way around that. Multiple return values are not supported in Java. But I would rather look at the solution from the design point of view. If a class needs to return multiple distinct values, then it probably does a lot of stuff, some of it unrelated to others. A single piece of code (a class, a method) should always have a single clear purpose and clearly defined responsibilities. Rather that returning multiple distinct values, I would consider splitting the method into multiple shorter method or define an inteface to externalise all the functionality. If those return values are related in any way and wouldn't have meaning if taken apart, then I think they deserve a class on their own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the [Collection](http://www.falkhausen.de/en/diagram/html/java.util.Collection.html) class for this purpose. This [Lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html) may help you in deciding what is best suited for you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, I'm aware of this, I've clarified that I'm looking for any of the typical remedies of this.