# Retrieve corresponding values from given algorithm

Tags: java, data-structures

I am writing a code in which i need to do the following to proceed further

- User need to input 2 values let it be 20.0 and 40.0
- the values in corresponding input fields should extracted from structure.

Structure looks like this....

```
 key                    value

20.0,40.0              1,2,3,4
21.0,22.0              5,6,7,8
```

**Input:**     20.0  40.0

**output:**    1,2,3,4

I really do not understand how to proceed I had tried but I am unable to.I need some code snippet which can do this job.....

Thanks for your time in going through my question.

Comment: What particular structure is used? From the question it is unclear.

Comment: How can it be `HashTable`? You show that there are 8 values for 4 keys...

Comment: 2 values together as one value  and 4 values as one key i mean 20.0 and 40.0 together is value and 1,2,3,4 together is key

Comment: try to print the key string before to get from the map, maybe the way you are getting the .toString() is not doing what you except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just build two 'structures' that represent the 
key and value.

```
class Key {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    Key(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class value {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
    public int w;
    Key(int x, int y, int z, int w) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.w = w;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
HashMap<Key, Value> map;
map.put(new Key(20, 40), new Value(1,2,3,4));
```

Based on your constraints, you could also make these classes into tuple templates with some implementation of variable tuple length.

**EDIT:**
If you are accessing the keys in a hash table/map, and are not using the pointer to the key object to get it, you have to override `equals` and `hashCode`.

I suggest looking at this stack overflow post: [Java N-Tuple implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642452/java-n-tuple-implementation)

Here they describe a variable length tuple implementation with `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.

Comment: can you include the code to retrieve corresponding key values please