# Trying to pass multiple numbers into an array

Tags: java, arrays, list, int

So, I'm trying to find a way to put a list or something ('list' not being the actual Java definition of 'list', instead the vernacular usage) of numbers into an array. It would go like this:

```
Land FlintsFinger = new Land(0,0,1,0,9, 1 2 3);
```

With the latter digits then going into the array in Land(ignore the other numbers).

Is there any syntax to do this on the fly? I know in Python there are tuples, but are there any such things in Java?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand "With the latter digits then going into the array in Land(ignore the other numbers)".  What does the presence or absence of comma separators signify in the input?  What output do you want?  Are you really asking about variable-length parameter lists? ...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't make this totally clear. So the last three digits are there because I don't know what to do with them yet. The true original code only has those first five digits - I don't know what to put those last three digits in or around in order to make them get picked up by the array in Land, so I left out the commas. It doesn't have an useful purpose at the moment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Tuples in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-tuples-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like:

```
public class Land {

    private final int[] values;

    public Land(int... values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Or if the first five parameters mean something else:

```
public Land(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int... values) {
    this.values = values;
}
```

Then call it as:

```
new Land(0,0,1,0,9, 1, 2, 3);
```

The compiler will put the final three values into an array for you. There's no literal form just using spaces though.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like this:

```
Land FlintsFinger = new Land(0,0,1,0,9, new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

Or you can change the constructor to:

```
public Land(int fst, int scn, int thr, int frth, int ffth, int... vals){}
```

and call it with

```
Land FlintsFinger = new Land(0,0,1,0,9,1,2,3);
```

(Your constructor could be shortened to `public Land(int... vals)` if all of the original values you enter are ints)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Land(Integer int1, Integer... ints){}
```

You mean varags: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/using-the-varargs-language-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

You could change your constructor to take in an array of ints

```
int [] params = new int{1,2,3};
Land FlintsFinger = new Land(0,0,1,0,9, params);
```