# Return x param anonymous object

Tags: java

In Java, sometimes I need to return a struct variable like Point(x,y). However, I only use this result in 1 place of the code and 1 time. So it seems excessive to declare a class called Point. Is there a way to return some kind of anonymous object with x number of parameters?

Comment: return int[] with two elements.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem that removes all semantics of what each element is, and it need not be both ints.

Comment: I believe OP is looking for something like perl's `my ($one, $two) = get_two();`

Comment: @KarthikT I responded based on 'Point(x,y)' as mentioned by poster.

Comment: You can try writing something like a generic tuple class and using those to return your values, this could then be reused in other parts of your code - see [Using Tuples in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2670982) for more info

Comment: or an `Object[]` with two elements if not both ints

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968265/return-more-than-one-variable-from-java-method?lq=1

Comment: +1 for declaring a class called `Point`, -1 for _thinking_ that's excessive.  Java deliberately doesn't provide tuple classes because it really isn't that difficult to write your own custom one with useful names for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can return an `ArrayList`, but then the problem is, an `ArrayList` is bound to one specific type, so if those parameters have different types, you have to typecast them. In your example, `x` and `y` are of type `int` or `double` I guess, but still.

If you want some 'anonymous' class, it still needs a class signature. You might want to make `Point` as an innerclass, something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    class Point {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    private Point p;
}
```

Why nested classes? [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) `Point` out why.

Answer (score 0):

You can return `Array` or `ArrayList`.

```
int[] GetPoint( ... )
{
    int[] arr = null;
    // ...
    // Find length (say len)

    arr = new int[len];

    // Business logic
    // ...

    return arr;
}
```