# How can I have to values be used in an either/or manner?

Tags: variables, dynamic, int

I am trying to make simple poker game and came to point where the 'number' for an Ace could be either a 13 or a 0 (Ace high vs Ace low).  As I am using a Bubble sort to determine straights, I wanted to assign the number of the Ace to both 1 and 13.  I Know Java doesn't support dynamic variables, but is there a method that returns an int of both values in such a way it is read as either/or?

Answer (score 0):

why you just dont return a vector of two elements?
another way it would be to create a tuple in Java, the solution is here:
[Using Pairs or 2-tuples in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-tuples-in-java)

Comment: Oh tuples.   I like that concept, was looking for something similar on another project ty.   for this one though, I think it will just end up being an if then in a 'hand' class 'sort' method.   the other idea that occurred to me was if I could define my own primitive type, like a number class that has ONLY 14 numbers and loops around on itself.  tried looking for it, but got nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If on each iteration of bubble sort, you do a comparison that has 2 possible values, you'd end up inconsistent sorts depending on how you compare, for example:

what would you expect the sort result to be from these inputs:
 K(11), A(01,13), Q(12)
Where would you expect A to be after the first step, position 1 or position 3?

The simplest thing would probably be to sort it twice, each with the different value for Ace

Comment: i actually created a class called card {
private string suit; //clubs, hearts etc
private string face; //jack, ten, deuce etc
private int count; //this to determine runs
private int value; //this to determine value, ace 14 deuce 1 }

Comment: the count value is only to determine run not value, hence it could be either 0 or 13 as it could end or start a run.  the value will determine its place in the hand (high to low, left to right)