# RowMapper with multiple classes

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, spring-data

I have two services defined:

```
Class cars
 model, year, mileage

Class driver
 name, age, licExpDate
```

I've put queries for each in their own service i.e. queries relating to cars in `car` and queries relating to drivers in `driver`. Furthermore I have `RowMapper` in each service

```
class CarRowMapper implements RowMapper<Car>{
    @Override
    public Car mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Car car = new Car();
                car.setModel(rs.getString("model"));
        return car;
    }       
}
```

**Question**
Now I need to export some data out for which I need to write a query which will involve columns for both `car` and `driver` in one query:

For example:

```
SELECT A.CAR B.NAME FROM CAR A, DRIVER B WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

So, now how can I have multiple classes in my RowMapper so that I can write a method like this:

```
public List<Cars> carsWithDrivers() {
  String query "...";
  return service.getJdbcTemplate().query(query, Row_mapper_here?));
}
```

Comment: i think you need to have a separate domain object CarWithDriver and a CarWithDriverRowmapper

Comment: Or use a [tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-tuples-in-java) to hold Car and Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the class you are going to use implementing RowMapper is MapCarWithDriver. Now inside it, there will be a mapRow(ResultSet, int rowNum) method being overridden. This will be called for each row of the resultSet of executed Query. So now you can create you own Driver object by

`Driver driver1 = new Driver();`
`driver1.setName(rset.getString("NAME");`
`Car car1= new Car(driver1);`
`car1.setModel(rset.getString("CAR");`