# Java: Vector with multiple generics

Tags: java, generics, vector

Is it possible to take objects like a Vector and make it have multiple generics? I know it's possible when you create a class, but will other classes that come with the normal Java API (like Vectors, Stack, etc.) can have multiple generics?

For example:

```
Vector<String, Integer> vect = new Vector<String, Integer>();
vect.add("Hello!", 0);
```

From this, one index would have two values, a String and Integer.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Related: [What is the equivalent of the C++ Pair<L,R> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156275/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-c-pairl-r-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-tuples-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Vector` class implements a growable array of objects, I think you are looking for map, `java.util.Map<key,value>`, implementation of map is `HashMap<k,v>`

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,"str");
```

Comment: I've never used a HashMap. How similar is it to a HashTable?

Comment: I guess Map<k,v> and HashMap<k,v> can only be called with two generics? for example: you can't call Map<v> or HashMap<v>

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a Vector is you can use a List.  In your case you need to use a custom class like

```
class MyClass {
    String s;
    int i;

    MyClass(String s, int i) {
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }
}

List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
list.add(new MyClass("Hello!", 0));

String s = list.get(0).s;
int i = list.get(0).i;
```

Answer (score 3):

Collections, e.g.  Vector, can only contain 1 type of object. You are trying to store 2 objects. Create a class called StringIntegerTuple that holds 2 references to the objects you want to store, then declare a Vector and store the composite objects instead.

Although semantically it is likely you want a HashMap

Comment: Creating such a tuple class is imo way overkill. OO should be used if it adds value, not just for the sake of it! http://prog21.dadgum.com/156.html