# How can I initialize List<List<T>> with values in one line and then iterate through the pairs?

Tags: java, list, iteration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initialization of an ArrayList in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line)

I am new to java and have a few question about lists.

I got defined variables x and y.

I want to create a list with lists of containing {x+1,y+1}, {x-1,y-1} etc
I tried something like this:

```
List<List<T>> currentList;
```

and then try to add items to it, but then it does not work

Is there an easy way to define such list in one line?
Is it possible then iterate through the pairs of values to manipulate them?

Any help is much appreciate!!! :)

Comment: Why don't you use 2 dimensional arrays for this?

Comment: It almost seems like you want to use a [`List<Tuple>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2671052/114359) instead.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in one line?

Comment: @MiserableVariable obviously (I'm not an op), because it will bring a lot of burden into code with all that .add .add ... guys.