# Simplist way to create a tuple in java?

Tags: java, tuples

Is there a simple way to create a 2 element tuple in java? I'm thinking of making a class and declaring the variables as final. Would this work?

Comment: `final` variables will work fine. Check out this question for a generic Tuple class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-tuples-in-java

Comment: *"Would this work?"*  What happened when you *tried it?*

Answer (score 7):

This is as simple as it gets:

```
public class Pair<S, T> {
    public final S x;
    public final T y;

    public Pair(S x, T y) { 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Best practices would be to make the fields private and provide getters for them.

For many people (including [most of?] the language designers), the idea of a tuple runs counter to the strong typing philosophy of Java. Rather than just a tuple, they would prefer a use-case-specific class, and if that class only has two getters and no other methods, so be it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the variables private with getters, no setters.
Set in the constructor, obviously.
Then implement iterable, maybe.

Comment: Iterable likely isn't appropriate. `Iterable<T>` is for something with some number of elements, all of type `T`. A tuple is, in general, a heterogeneous structure (its two elements may be of different types).