# Java - Map with key, keyTitle, value, valueTitle

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I need to use some kind of double map in my project. I can imagine this as Map with common key and triple value, but maybe there's better option.
Is there any implementations of this kind of map? Maybe some free library?

Comment: Add some sample data.

Comment: Triple value, as in 3 values for 1 key? Or multiple values for 1 key? You could either create a new type `NewValue` (to create objects which contain those values), then use `<KeyType, NewValue>`. Or you could use a `List` as the value, which can contain multiple elements.

Comment: You mean a  multimap ? - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html

Comment: I thought about creating new type with 3 fields and then just use Map with this type, but it looks a little awkward.

Comment: Multimap is not really what I need, I need exactly 3 values for one key, not the Collection

Answer (score 1):

Create two small Java POJOs for title and value attributes `MyKey` and `MyValue` and you can now have `Map<MyKey, MyValue>` in this case you can extend the attributes of the `Key` and `Value` in future.

Comment: The problem is how could I get value from Map only by key, not by key and keyTitle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Triplet from http://www.javatuples.org/.

Or, you could create your own class, like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671052/5066232.

Comment: Its better as a comment