# How to sort ArrayList according to another ArrayList?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I've got two `ArrayList<JLabel>`:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> label1 = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JLabel> label2 = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
```

`label1` contains names (like "John" or "car") and `label2` contain ratings (like "8.5" or "10.0"). I wanna sort both lists by rating.

I've used `Collections.sort(label2, new Sort());` to sort `label2`, but I have no idea how to sort `label1` in exaclty the same way (using `label2` objects). Here is my `Comparator` class:

```
class Sort implements Comparator<JLabel>{
    public int compare(JLabel o1, JLabel o2) {
        Double a = Double.parseDouble(o1.getText());
        Double b = Double.parseDouble(o2.getText());
        return  b.compareTo(a);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example input-output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have no relationship defined between the two lists I think you should consider wrapping the two values up in a class:

```
class Foo {

   private String name;
   private double rating;

   public Foo(String name, double rating){
       this.name = name;
       this.rating = rating;
   }

   // getters & setters
}
```

You can then have `List<Foo>` and sort the list based on the value of rating.

In Java 8 this would be as simple as calling the `sort()` method, which is now provided in `List`, with a lambda expression passed in.

Comment: In addition to this answer I would add that you can use a method reference to sort. `list.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Foo::getRating))`

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this using a `Map`. We'll first define a comparator to sort descending by value, like so:

```
class NumericComparator extends Comparator {
    Map map;
    public NumericComparator(Map map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Integer) map.get(o2)).compareTo((Integer) map.get(o1));
    }
}
```

We'll define the name as the key, and the rating as the value. Like so:

```
Map<String, Double> carMap = new HashMap<>();
//we can populate the map like so:
carMap.put("John", 10d); //works nicely in loops
```

Then we take that unsorted map, and insert all of it's values into a `TreeMap`, that implements the `NumericComparator` we defined earlier.

```
NumericComparator nc = new NumericComparator(carMap);
Map<String, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap(nc);
sortedMap.putAll(carMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please program to the `List` interface. Next, I'm assuming you can use apache libraries, there is [`Pair<L, R>`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) in [apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) (or you could implement your own tuple class; or use another like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671052/2970947)). Regardless, you'll need to modify your `Comparator` to operate on the right-hand side (and I personally like to use the left-hand side to break ties). Finally, if you want to use `label1` and `label2` you'll need to copy the values back (after sorting). Something like,

```
List<JLabel> label1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<JLabel> label2 = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
List<Pair<JLabel, JLabel>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
int len = label1.size();
if (len == label2.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        pairs.add(Pair.of(label1.get(i), label2.get(i)));
    }
    Collections.sort(pairs, new Comparator<Pair<JLabel, JLabel>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<JLabel, JLabel> o1,
                Pair<JLabel, JLabel> o2) {
            double a = Double.parseDouble(o1.getRight().getText());
            double b = Double.parseDouble(o2.getRight().getText());
            int ret = Double.compare(a, b);
            if (ret != 0) {
                return ret;
            } // if ret is 0, it's a tie.
            return o1.getLeft().getText()
                    .compareTo(o2.getLeft().getText());
        }
    });
    // ... only if you need to use label1 and label2 after the sort.
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        label1.set(i, pairs.get(i).getLeft());
        label2.set(i, pairs.get(i).getRight());
    }
}
```