# How to put List data with different generic type with same Return type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, drools

My problem is that `ClassB` is a common bean class i have to return(Json data format using `@ResponseBody` ) simple error message. **ClassA is an Entity bean** there no setter and getter method to set the error message to the `fstList, fstListMap` . If there is any alternate solution or else any merging solution for `fstListMap,errsecstMap` Object to return common Map Object . If any changes only `ClassA` bean is **changeable** but `ClassB` **Not** changeable.

```
@RequestMapping(value="getlistOfData",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, List<ClassA>>
getListOfData(@RequestParam(value="param1")String
                      param1,@RequestParam(value="param2")int param2){

    List<ClassA> fstList=new ArrayList<ClassA>();//ClassA is an hibernate Entity
    Map<String, List<ClassA>> fstListMap=new HashMap<String, List<ClassA>>();

    List<ClassB> errsecstList=new ArrayList<ClassB>();//It is simple Bean class
    Map<String, List<ClassB>> errsecstMap=new HashMap<String, List<ClassB>>();
    ClassB clB=new ClassB();
    boolean isvalid=true;
    try{


        isvalid=newllbean.getisInvalidAge();//This value return drools (set in rule file)
        if(isvalid){//if true then go to this condition
            fstList=serviceClass.getfstList()
            fstListMap.put("fstList", fstList);
            System.out.println("fstList Size: "+fstListMap.size());
            System.out.println("fstList : "+fstListMap);//Am getting this data
        }else{
            String errMessage=clB.setErrorMessage("Age Not valid...");
            errsecstList.add(clB.getErrorMessage());
            errsecstMap.put("errorMessage",errsecstList);
            System.out.println("errMessage Size: "+errsecstMap.size());
            System.out.println("errMessage : "+errsecstMap);//I am getting this value
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception"+e);
    }
    return fstListMap;
}
```

> how to return errsecstMap?

there is a no parameter to set the `errMessage` in `ClassA` entity. I want to return single Map object either if or else condition. There is any solution to return common Map Object to return based on the above code?

Comment: You told the problem but it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Update some explanation here what you want to achieve and source code for classA at least as you can't change classB.

Comment: So you want a tuple? `class Tuple<A, B> {A a; B b;}` Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670982/using-pairs-or-2-tuples-in-java Or an optional? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: @Akash - I trying get error message in json  if isvalid is false. But my return type is Map<String, List<ClassA>> like this. Actually setter error message in ClassB bean. I said If required  to change as per required ClassB  bean is changeable.

Comment: @Locke...Thank you! Can you please give clear picture according to above snippet. I am not clear tuple.

Comment: @veer so you want to return both the cases - correct data for successful cases, error for invalid cases using same return. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Akash--yes correct.

Comment: Create a class for your return with JSON.INCLUDE(notnull) with both the maps. If valid, set error map to null. If invalid, set valueMap to null in your code and return the object. This way you'll be able to send both the things. I try to paste sample code here in sometime.

Comment: @veer you can further use generics to simplify your class design a lot. :-) Let me know if you need with class design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (this is not compiled) -

1) Create a Response class like this -

```
import java.util.List;

public class ResponseClass<T> {

    public String str;
    public List<T> list;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

2) Modify your existing class like this -

```
@RequestMapping(value="getlistOfData",method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseClass<T>
getListOfData(@RequestParam(value="param1")String
                      param1,@RequestParam(value="param2")int param2){

    List<ClassA> fstList=new ArrayList<ClassA>();//ClassA is an hibernate Entity
    ResponseClass<ClassA> responseA = new ResponseClass<>();

    List<ClassB> errsecstList=new ArrayList<ClassB>();//It is simple Bean class
    ResponseClass<ClassB> responseB = new ResponseClass<>();

    ClassB clB=new ClassB();
    boolean isvalid=true;

    try{


        isvalid=newllbean.getisInvalidAge();//This value return drools (set in rule file)
        if(isvalid){//if true then go to this condition
            fstList=serviceClass.getfstList()
            responseA.setStr("fstList");
            responseA.setList(fstList);
            System.out.println("fstList Size: "+fstListMap.size());
            System.out.println("fstList : "+fstListMap);//Am getting this data
            return responseA;
        }else{
            String errMessage=clB.setErrorMessage("Age Not valid...");
            errsecstList.add(clB.getErrorMessage());
            responseB.setStr("errorMessage");
            responseB.setList(errsecstList);
            System.out.println("errMessage Size: "+errsecstMap.size());
            System.out.println("errMessage : "+errsecstMap);//I am getting this value
            return responseB;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception"+e);
    }
}
```

Obviously, above code can be easily optimized based on your user case. This is a simple implementation.